# Disable UI elements using UIAutomator

Tags: android-uiautomator

Is there a way to disable Android UI elements such as editview,button, notification area and soft keyboard using UIAutomator.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can only perform actions on `Views` via their `UiObject` representation such as clear, click, setText, etc. but you cannot change the internal View state like setEnabled.

To dismiss the soft keyboard you can send `BACK`.